# Python black and normal formatter not working

Tags: python, formatter

I've seen some videos and explanations but nothing worked for me.

In the output it says:

- Waiting for interpreter from python extension.
- No interpreter found from setting black-formatter.interpreter
- Getting interpreter from ms-python.python extension for workspace
- Interpreter from ms-python.python extension for c:\Users

Additionally i found

- black, 23.3.0 (compiled: no)

Some sources told me to change some stuff in the settings.json which i did:

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter"
```

I'm running out of ideas, neither black nor the "normal" formatter are working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated